# Nuxt.js - How to populate initial vuex state on application startup just in server side?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I need to have “countries” data from an api and it should not be called on each request. So I am planning to call this api on initial app startup (running once) and assign api response to the vuex state. Therefore state will be populated only once and all coming request will get populated state from nuxt server. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt exposes the `nuxtServerInit` that you can define as an action in your top level store (only in the top level!), and will be called once when the server starts.

```
export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit({ commit }, { req }) {
    // Here you can commit changes to the state
    // or call some service you have. Example:
    const countries = await api.get('/countries');
    commit('setCountries', { countries });
  }
};
```

Comment: nuxtServerInit works in request scope so if you debug your code you will see that it's called on each request to the server. What i need to do is to call country api and populate state once then each request gets data from populated state.

Comment: I would like to see, or at least know more of your code, because what you said doesn't make sense to me. Is it a universal application?

Comment: Ok I'm thinking now and I think I understand. What server do you have running on the backend? some sort of ExpressJS, NestJS or so? In that case you'll need to do some middleware to fetch the countries, and be passed to the frontend (in case you need it in the frontend) with nuxtServerInit, just like the example in the docs: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action

Comment: I think makmonty's solution is fine, and you don't have to worry about `nuxtServerInit` being called on every subsequent request (in the same browser session). Seeing `req` passed seems completely reasonable considering the initial request is a... request. This can all be confirmed by simply putting a console.log within and just watching if it's called more than once for a given session.